# Is there a Browser-based wallet for Cardano?

Tags: wallet

**Will we have a Cardano Browser Wallet**?

Something like Metamask on Ethereum.

Answer (score 13):

Updated: April 18, 2023.

### Native Web3 wallet

Today (April 18) IOG released a native [browser-based](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/lace/gafhhkghbfjjkeiendhlofajokpaflmk) Cardano 1.0 wallet called **Lace** (I believe it's still about Lovelace ), with digital assets, easy staking, NFT gallery and DApp Connector. Lace 1.0 wallet currently supports only Google Chrome.

---

[image]

---

### Third party wallets

There's the open-source [*Nami Wallet*](https://namiwallet.io) – a browser-based wallet extension to interact with the Cardano blockchain. You can run it on Edge, Brave, Chrome and any other chrome-based browsers. As you can imagine, the Berry Pool's wallet does support staking. And it has nice and simple UI.

> The user of Nami wallet can only import one seed phrase, but from that one they can create sub-accounts. Each account is its own wallet and independent from each other.

---

[image]

---

Also, you can try 4 other ***web wallets*** that support ADA and tokens:

- [ccvault](https://linktr.ee/ccvaultio) – Wallet staking, external/internal addresses, hardware wallets support, multiple wallets/accounts, browser extension option
- [GUARDA](https://guarda.com) – Crypto exchange and external staking
- [SimpleHold](https://simplehold.io) – Private key import, hardware wallets support
- [GameChanger](https://gamechanger.finance/index.html) – DApps cart, playground editor

Comment: Do you know if they still only allow staking to Berry pool?

Comment: Hi Matthew, I'll add it to my answer in 45 mins...

Comment: Thanks Andy. I just went and checked the site. They will support staking integrations through 'external staking interfaces' e.g. an SPO website. And only BERRY staking is supported in the wallet itself.

Answer (score 9):

We have Yoroi Web extensión for Chrome, Firefox and Edge.

[www.yoroi-wallet.com](http://www.yoroi-wallet.com)

Comment: I wouldn't recommend yoroi. It's not very actively being developed/ enhanced.
Check out Eternl.io (formerly CCVault.io) or Nami (very simple) or soon Lace.io

Answer (score 2):

It's called [Yoroi](https://yoroi-wallet.com/#/). It's a browser extension like Metamask.

Answer (score 1):

There is something similar, though it's more a "web wallet", not a browser plugin wallet like Metamask.
Checkout [AdaLite](https://adalite.io/)

Answer (score 1):

[GeroWallet](https://gerowallet.io/) was launched a couple of weeks ago and it works exactly like Yoroi.

Answer (score 1):

**Eternl** (https://eternl.io/), previously known as *ccvault.io*, provides browser extension (DApp connector & DApp Browser) for Chrome, Edge, Brave and Opera browser.

- **DApp Browser**: users can connect their wallets to DApps listed in Eternl's DApp Browser.
- Supports different **testnet networks** or other supported Cardano based networks.
- **TxBuilder** feature: it allows you to add multiple outputs to a transaction and choose which utxos you want to spend. It also has support for custom json metadata.
- **Dark Mode**.

The team consists of developers of community stake pools **[TITAN] TITANstaking** and **[AHL] AHLNET**.

Answer (score 0):

Here’s a growing list:

Yoroi (legacy, by Emurgo)

Nami (by BERRY stake pool, supports testnet)

ccvault.io (coming soon for browser extension)

Flint (new but nice, by dc_Spark / Sebastian)

Gero (nice UI)

Answer (score -1):

There is Yoroi, developed bei Emurgo, which also has a PC program and also a mobile app.

Answer (score -1):

Yoroi is the famous one for ADA browser wallets.